# modified Merkle-Damgard construction that does not include message length

Tags: hash, merkle-damgaard

How to give an example for collision in modified Mekle-Damgard construction that does not include input length, with two message that **ARE** multiple of the block length? (Assume the resulting hash function is only defined for inputs whose length is an integer multiple of the block length.) 
It is easy to consider a counter-example in the case where two messages have lengths that are not an integer multiple of the block length. Like: if block length be *n* and *x* be a string of *mn+n-2* bits, then H(x|00)=H(x0|0), i.e., *x* and *x0* have the same hash value.
[image: Introduction to modern cryptography, Katz and Lindell, 2nd Edition]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this be an answer for this question:
When messages are an integer multiple of the block length, **counter-examples are possible, though they rely on a contrived compression function h, as Katz-Lindell said.**
If $$h:\{0,1\}^{2n} \rightarrow \{0, 1\}^{n} \\ h(x_{1}\|x_{2})=h'(x_{1})$$ for some collision resistant hash function $h':\{0,1\}^{*} \rightarrow \{0,1\}^{n} $, then for two given messages $X=x_{1}\|x_{2}$ and $X'=x_{1}\|x_{2}\|x_{3}$ with lengths $|X|=2\ell$ and $|X'|=3\ell$, where $\ell$ is the block length, we have:
$$H(X)=h(x_{2}\|z_{1})=h'(x_{2}) \\ H(X')=h(x_{3}\|z_{2})=h'(x_{3})$$
Now, if we choose $x_{3}=x_{2}$, i.e., $X'=x_{1}\|x_{2}\|x_{2}$, then $H(X)=H(X')=h'(x_{2})$. So we found a collision.
**BUT** *is this a good counter-example?* 
Because with using this particular hash function, h, we do not use previous hash blocks and kind of making the Merkle-Damgard construction vain!

Comment: Answers go in the answer box, guesses may be included with the question.